# How to change default (3.x python) Google Colab environment to 2.x python?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want to run python `2.x` in Google Colab to train my network which is written in python `2.x`. https://github.com/you359/Keras-FasterRCNN. Unfortunately I could not do it right now. Few months ago I had an option to choose between `3.x` & `2.x`. But now the default is `3.x`.

I tried to install in my Jupyter notebook colab environment like this;

```
!sudo apt update
!sudo apt upgrade
!sudo apt install python2.7
```

But still the it shows the python version as;

```
!python --version

> Python 3.6.9
```

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [frequently asked questions](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html) from Google colab,one can see that python 2 is no longer supported and has been removed from change Runtime Type option too.

**When will Colab phase-out Python 2?**
The Python development team has declared that Python 2 will no longer be supported after January 1st, 2020. As of that date, Colab has stopped updating Python 2 runtimes, and will begin phasing out support for Python 2 in the following months.

For users, this means that for the time being, Python 2 notebooks will continue to work. However, at some point in the future Python 2 notebooks may begin to connect to a Python 3 runtime instead. To avoid surprises, we suggest migrating important notebooks to Python 3.